# Homomorphism extension between fundamental groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, abstract-algebra

I have the following problem. Let $X$ be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $Y$ some topological space. Also, let $\psi: (X,x_0) \to (Y,y_0)$ be a continuous map. If there exists a continuous extension of $\psi$, say $\tilde{\psi}: \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$, then $\psi$ induces a trivial homomorphism in the fundamental groups (I guess of $X$ and $Y$)?

Not only I cannot show the above but also I am not sure I understand the question..

Comment: The fundamental group is functorial, $$(X,x_0) \xrightarrow{f} (Y,y_0) \xrightarrow{g} (Z,z_0)$$ becomes $$\pi_1(X,x_0) \xrightarrow{f_\ast} \pi_1(Y,y_0) \xrightarrow{g_\ast} \pi_1(Z,z_0).$$

Comment: Sorry, I do not know what this exactly means and/or how to related with the proof I want to show. But thanks.

Comment: Can you see how the existence of an extension $\tilde{\psi}$ allows you to write $\psi$ as a composition of two continuous maps, one to $\mathbb{R}^n$, the next with domain $\mathbb{R}^n$? Then the above shows what you want to show.

Comment: I am still struggling with this. Is it possible to have a more detailed explanation? Thanks

Comment: Let $\iota$ be the inclusion of $X$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so $\iota(x) = x$ for $x\in X$. What is $\tilde{\psi}\circ \iota$?

Comment: $i : Y \to X$ . Then $\tilde{\psi} \circ i : \mathbb{R}^n \to Y$, right? Hm, I am really do not know.. Ehm, I cannot follow, sorry.

Comment: No, $\iota \colon X \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be a subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $Y$ be some topological space.

Consider the inclusion function $j : X \to \mathbb R^n$ where $x \mapsto x$.

Suppose you have $\varphi : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ a continuous map that extends to $\mathbb R^n$, that is, there exists $k : (\mathbb R^n, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ such that $k \vert_X = \varphi$. But recall that $k \vert_X = k \circ j = \varphi$ since we have $$(X, x_0) \xrightarrow{j} (\mathbb R^n, x_0) \xrightarrow{k} (Y, y_0)$$ which induces $$\pi_1(X, x_0) \xrightarrow{j_*} \pi_1(\mathbb R^n, x_0) \xrightarrow{k_*} \pi_1(Y, y_0).$$

Notice that $\pi_1(\mathbb R^n, x_0) = 0$ since $R^n$ is convex and thus every loop contracts to a point via the straight line homotopy, so $k_*$ is trivial.

We want to show that $\varphi_* : \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ is trivial.

But since $\varphi = k \circ j$, then $\varphi_* = k_* \circ j_*$.

Take a loop $f$ based at $x_0$ in $X$ and consider $[f] \in \pi_1(X, x_0)$. Observe that $\varphi_*\big([f]\big) = k_*\big(j\big([f]\big)\big) = k_*\big([f]\big) = 0$.

Conclude that $\varphi_*$ is trivial.